# How do I exit nano in Emacs 26.3?

Tags: emacs, nano

I'd like to know how to close `nano` under a `term` using `/bin/bash`, all under the context of in `emacs -nw`. A plain `^X` doesn't work.

I tried entering the character mode using `C-c C-k`, but that didn't seem to help. Is there another "just send this along" command for a key binding?

Comment: So, you're running `emacs -nw`, then `M-x term` (`/bin/bash`), and then `nano`? Which version of Emacs are you running? `C-x` works fine for me to end `nano`.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I updated the title and the question to answer these questions. If you can exit fine, then this may be a configuration problem. I'll check on this.

Comment: Maybe you need `C-q C-x` to quote the `C-x` to emacs, so that it can be passed to nano.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> will be interpreted by nano in the same manner as C-x.

Background: A [sometimes-]handy nano tip: press Esc twice followed by the desired key to send the equivalent Ctrl- command.